# Users seeing the Unverified App Screen in the android app

Tags: google-oauth, google-fit

We have android application that uses Fitness API for reading steps.

Our app has passed OAuth verification process and ***./auth/fitness.activity.read*** scope was approved:
[image]

In the app we request "fitness read" permission using this part of the code:

```
val fitnessOptions = FitnessOptions.builder()
        .addDataType(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_READ)
        .build()
    GoogleSignIn.requestPermissions(
        this,
        1000,
        GoogleSignIn.getAccountForExtension(requireContext(), fitnessOptions),
        fitnessOptions
    )
```

But unverified OAuth consent screen still appears:

[image]

GCP Technical Support didn't help with it and asked us to report this problem here.

**Any ideas what's wrong?** Maybe someone had similar issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in **OAuth Client ID**.
We had 2 projects in Google Cloud Console: for *prod* and for *dev*.
OAuth consent screen was verified for prod one.

*Prod* and *dev* projects had Client IDs for the same package name and certificate and my prod app has used Client ID of the *dev* project.

Answer (score 0):

That screen indicates that your app is in "testing" state: https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/10311615#zippy=%2Ctesting.

You will need to switch your app to production state. Before doing so, please confirm that your app is requesting only scopes that it has already been approved to use. If your app is using any sensitive scopes that are not approved, your users will see an unverified app screen. You can determine what scopes your app is using by inspecting your code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but application is in "production" state and requests only 1 sensitive scope (which is approved by google) as I mentioned in the question. Any other idea why it happens?